# Error:(8, 30) String types not allowed (at 'description' with value 'Public Albums of this username will be fetched')

Tags: android, android-resources, aapt, android-restrictions

I am trying to configure [restrictions](https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-restrictions.html) in my Application but I am getting following error

> Error:(8, 30) String types not allowed (at 'description' with value 'Public Albums of this username will be fetched').
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\athakur\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My app_restriction.xml is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<restrictions xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <restriction
        android:key="google_username"
        android:title="Google Username"
        android:restrictionType="string"
        android:description="Public Albums of this username will be fetched"
        android:defaultValue="opensourceforgeeks" />

</restrictions>
```

If I remove description it works fine. I have used same syntax as specified on [android dev page](https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-restrictions.html) i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<restrictions xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <restriction
    android:key="downloadOnCellular"
    android:title="App is allowed to download data via cellular"
    android:restrictionType="bool"
    android:description="If 'false', app can only download data via Wi-Fi"
    android:defaultValue="true" />

</restrictions>
```

Not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen if you use a string resource rather than hardcoded text?

Comment: Surprisingly using String resource worked and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description value for a Restriction element must be a String Resource, as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/RestrictionsManager.html). Extracting the hardcoded text will therefore fix the build.

Comment: By that logic it also says `android:title="string resource"` but as you see I am using plane String and not String resource.

Comment: The title attribute allows both: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#RestrictionEntry_title

Comment: Well they should update the [main documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-restrictions.html#define_restrictions) then. Not every developer goes and sees specs of every small API argument.

Answer (score 1):

As @fractalwrench correctly pointed out description attribute can only point to a resource [ [this documentation example](https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-restrictions.html#define_restrictions) is misleading. Plain text is not allowed ].

> public static final int RestrictionEntry_description
>
> Must be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol description.
>   Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#RestrictionEntry_description)

Following worked for me

```
<restriction
    android:key="google_username"
    android:title="Google Username"
    android:restrictionType="string"
    android:description="@string/rest_uname_desc"
    android:defaultValue="opensourceforgeeks" />
```

with

```
<string name="rest_uname_desc">Public Albums of this username will be fetched</string>
```

in string.xml